# calculate the 3D angle of an object (knowing its orientation)

Tags: 3d, projective-geometry

I'm not a mathematician, but I'm trying to solve a (javascript) code problem.
What I need, if I express correctly, is a formula to get the angles of a 3D object,..knowing its rotation ?

Well, maybe it would be easier to understand with pictures :

[image]

I'm working on a javascript animation which consists of a fake 3D cylinder rotating on its Z axis. I've done it within After Effects but whatever, this is a code/maths question.

I have a "Zrot" variable driving some shapes changes, which "simulates" a rotating 3D object on one axis - so this is not 3D but 2D.

Now I need to be able to rotate my layer, but when doing it, the angle looks weird.

[image]

What I'm searching for is a formula to calculate a "zrot" offset based on the layer rotation.

```
var frontRot = 78;
var zRot = -33;

var zRotOffset = frontRot * ...
zRot = zRot + zRotOffset;
```

[image]

If you know some 3D softwares, it is kind of like local rotation VS global rotation.

[image]

Can anyone help ?  I need something that could be coded in javascript.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you rotating the faces of the cylinder about the geometric center of the cylinder, or are you rotating each face about its own center?

Comment: OK, it appears that you are doing the former. All good. I added the projective geometry tag, which should bring more attention to your question. It's been decades since I did image modeling, I'm afraid.